# objective-c union "->" vs "."

Tags: objective-c, c

let me start by saying i am pretty new to the whole struct and union thing. i have done my homework before posting this and honestly trying to get legitimate clarification. if this is the wrong way to this please let me know. first off, i am attempted to create a union because i am combining different data types. my only real problem / question is the dot operator vs the ->. i can get what i want working using the

```
->
```

but not the

```
.
```

im just curious as to why? iv read a bunch of posts on stack that show examples or "answers" using the ".", but no luck in the real world. i have played with "typedef" like...

```
typedef union _myUnion
{
     int intValue;
     bool boolValue;
}myUnion;
```

but that doesn't seam to make a difference. if anyone explain what im doing wrong it would be greatly appreciated. here is a quick sample of what i am trying to do. for the sake of simplicity, i will just post some struct/union syntax and wont add any of the sub-classing code since that's not an issue.

example.h

```
#import "<Foundation/Foundation.h"

union myUnion
{
   int intValue;
   bool boolValue;
};

@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    union myUnion *someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) union myUnion *someProperty;

-(void)doSomething;

@end
```

example.m

```
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

@synthesize someProperty = _someProperty;

- (id)init
{
//Some init method...
}

- (void)doSomething
{
    NSLog(@"I Did Something...");
}

@end
```

so now in my other class this works...

```
MyClass *newObject = [MyClass alloc] init];
newObject.someProperty->intValue = 6;
```

but this doesn't...

```
MyClass *newObject = [MyClass alloc] init];
newObject.someProperty.intValue = 6;
```

at this point in time i'm more interested in learning why that latter doesn't work? what's interesting is if i take off the pointer in the .h file for the property.

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
    {
        union myUnion someProperty;
    }

@property (nonatomic, assign) union myUnion someProperty;
```

the "." works instead of the "->", but now its not assignable.

as a side note, if i change the bool to an int and make it a struct the same thing happens. unfortunately i became proficient at objective-c first and am slowly picking up strict c as i go. so my understanding of c is a tad weak, but that's the beauty of obc, i get to learn two languages for the price of one! if you don't count open-gl.

i would ask, if someone could post a working example of code and i can then figure out what i did wrong, or explain thoroughly what it is i am doing wrong and some of the fundamental concepts i missed. from there i can figure out how to write my own working code. i don't need both, and don't expect a hand out but would like to learn so i can solve my own problems and not just patch buggy code without understanding how or why it works.

Answer (score 8):

The `a->b` operator is shorthand for `(*a).b` - it's like using the `.` but doing a dereference first. It's appropriate when `a` is a pointer.

Since in your original example `someProperty` is a pointer to a union, you'll need to dereference that pointer first. This means you'll need to either use:

```
(*newObject.someProperty).intValue // confusing!
```

Or

```
newObject.someProperty->intValue // much better
```

to access it.

Of course, once you've changed `someProperty` to be a union instead of a pointer to a union, you can use the `.` instead. So:

- `a->b`: Accesses a struct/union member on  a pointer
- `a.b`:  Accesses a struct/union member on a raw struct/union

Answer (score 5):

In this case, it's quite probable that you want the union as a value -- not a pointer to an external memory location:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    union myUnion someProperty; // << no '*'
}

@end
```

then you use the period for member access:

```
someProperty.intValue = 6;
```

and *if it were* a pointer:

```
someProperty->intValue = 6;
```

However, there's another issue. You have two (primary) options to use the union as a property.  Value or pointer. This is commonly handled by value, especially when all fields refer to  memory local to the structure/union, and when the field id not large. In this case, you would often return and set by value. This means that your program would be written as follows:

```
@interface MyClass : NSObject
{
    union myUnion someProperty;
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) union myUnion someProperty; // << by value

@end
```

then the client may access and set it by value, like so:

```
union myUnion p = obj.someProperty;
++p.intValue;
obj.someProperty = p;
```

and that's how it's *often* accomplished with small structures which don't refer to shared resources.

Of course, you will not need a copy when your instance has direct access to it, should you choose to access the field directly:

```
- (void)doSomething
{
  ++someProperty.intValue;
}
```

if this becomes complex, it's likely a good idea to *abstract* the data behind methods, and leave accessing and mutation to the instance of `MyClass` which holds the union.

Comment: the answers provided by you and timothy are wonderfully stated. thank you both. if i could ask a followup question. let's i was creating the ubiquitous "person" class. that "person" has a property of "hair". that hair has a "length" & "color". so if i wanted to set person.hair.color = black; & person.hair.length = long; would a struct be the right way to go, or should i be looking at doing this a different way? i guess i am trying to figure out is how to create "sub properties", then set and get those.

Comment: @DoS for nontrivial behaviors and data, you'd typically just use an objc class, rather than a plain c struct or union. with experience, you'll be able to choose objc class, c struct, or other appropriate design quite easily.

Comment: thanks again for the info. but to your point i am just trying to learn different methodologies for doing things. "broadening my horizons" so to speak. i know i could do this with a pure o-c class but was curious how else it could be done. i guess i am still a bit confused on my pseudo "sub property" question or syntax. using the "person" class example, you're basically saying "hair" would just be a sub-class of the "person" class. "length" & "color" would then just be properties of the hair sub-class? am i understanding that correctly?

Comment: @DoS it ultimately depends on the complexity and the behavior. one structure (c struct or objc class) is typically more favorable for a given task or implementation. in the case of the person, you may ultimately find that hair.length is most easily expressed using a c type, but hair has multiple properties, and it may have implementation or polymorphic behavior needed to represent hair as an object, so hair as a more complex representation, may be better suited to a class, while a int may be used for length, and an NSColor or UIColor may be used for the color property. (cont)

Comment: (cont) but many objc devs don't take c to its limits wrt ood, unless performance or portability is a concern. they just use objc types when it's easier to represent something as an objc type (or collection, or…).

Comment: i guess for my pseudo example i'd like to keep "person" as my object. so even if i had 3 person objects, they all have a hair property. this is really the best real world example i can give since i am just extrapolating ideas. the reason i am on this train of thought, is maybe person1 has a "beard" that follows the same "hair" etities. person2.hair.color = brown; person1.beard.color = black; i guess my end game is the most efecient and minimalistic coding approach. iv grown to understand o-c, now i am working on optimizing it. why do something with 10 lines if it can be done with 1?

Comment: my recommendation at that point would be to write some object-oriented-c libraries as you have outlined -- using c exclusively. this is just a learning experience, but it will help you to drive your programs down as you wish and force you to solve some of the problems and benefits of working with that feature set. write some without external libraries, write some with ext libs (e.g. core foundation).