# What data type needed to receive value from this function?

Tags: c, types

I need help figuring out the correct data type for an assignment from a function call please.

I'm trying to get at the data in the `content` field of `N_Vector u`. Here's what the documentation says about `N_Vector`:

> The type `N_Vector` is defined as
>
> ```
> N_Vector u;
> tpedef struct _generic_N_Vector *N_Vector;
> struct _generic_N_Vector {
>   void *content;
>   struct _generic_N_Vector_Ops *ops;
> };
> ```
>
> ...
>
> [The parallel NVECTOR module] defines the *content* field of `N_Vector`
>   to be a structure containing global and local lengths, a pointer to the
>   beginning of contiguous local data array, MPI communicator and flag.
>
> ```
> struct _N_VectorContent_Parallel {
>   long int local_length;
>   long int global_length;
>   booleantype own_data;
>   realtype *data;
>   MPI_Comm comm;
> }
> ```

So I guess that means that `content` in `_generic_N_Vector` "points to" a structure of type `_N_VectorContent_Parallel` (right?).

Then I try to use a macro for accessing `content`. Here's the documentation for `NV_CONTENT_P`.

> `v_cont=NV_CONTENT_P(v)` sets `v_cont` to be a pointer to the `N_Vector` content 
>   structure of type `struct _N_VectorParallelContent`.

Notice the different name of the struct!

*What does that mean? What type do I declare `v_cont` to be?*

I tried

```
N_Vector u;
...
_N_VectorParallelContent *v_cont1;
_N_VectorContent_Parallel *v_cont2;
v_cont1 = NV_CONTENT_P(u);
v_cont2 = NV_CONTENT_P(u);
```

but these declarations got the error "'_N_VectorContent_Parallel' undeclared..." or "'_N_VectorParallelContent' undeclared...".

But it seems that these structures *must* be delcared already. I successfully declared (and used) `u`, of type `N_Vector`. And the docs seem to say that `N_Vector` contains one of those two structures (or maybe both).

*So why the error message? What is the correct data type to declare for* `v_cont` *to receive data from* `NV_CONTENT_P`?

I know this is a long, detailed question, but I don't understand enough to whittle it down any more.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Timothy Indirectly. Actually using mpicc, which is (I'm told) a wrapper around gcc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not familiar with this particular library, but it looks to me like [the documentation](https://computation.llnl.gov/casc/sundials/documentation/kin_guide/node7.html#SECTION00720000000000000000) is a little inconsistent.

Right after the blurb about `NV_CONTENT_P(v)`, it says `NV_CONTENT_P(v)` is defined as:

```
#define NV_CONTENT_P(v) ( (N_VectorContent_Parallel)(v->content) )
```

So that version of the name is probably correct. I can't see a definition for `N_VectorContent_Parallel` on that page, but it's probably defined somewhere as something like `struct _N_VectorContent_Parallel*`. So, you can probably do:

```
N_VectorContent_Parallel v_cont1 = NV_CONTENT_P(u);
```

Remember that for structs, `struct` is part of the type name. This means that you're getting errors in your example because you haven't included `struct`:

```
// this is an unknown type
_N_VectorParallelContent *v_cont1; 

// this is a "struct _N_VectorParallelContent"
struct _N_VectorParallelContent *v_cont1; 

// But use this one, as it follows the macro
N_VectorContent_Parallel v_cont1;
```

---

If you want to see exactly what the preprocessor has done to your code, you can use gcc's `-E` flag.

> ```
> -E    Stop after the preprocessing stage; do not run the compiler proper. 
>    The output is in  the form of preprocessed source code, which is sent to 
>    the standard output.
>    Input files which don't require preprocessing are ignored.
> ```

This is especially useful for seeing the results of macros and multiple complex header files.

---

**Edit:** From the source you've linked:

```
typedef struct _N_VectorContent_Parallel *N_VectorContent_Parallel;
```

This is a type definition that says that `N_VectorContent_Parallel` is the same as a `struct _N_VectorContent_Parallel *` (a pointer to a `struct _N_VectorContent_Parallel`), which means you can access `v_cont1` using the `->` syntax:

```
N_VectorContent_Parallel v_cont1;
printf("%d",v_cont1->local_length);
```

`a->b` is is shorthand for `(*a).b` - it's just a cleaner-looking way of writing the dereference needed to accessing a member of a struct through a pointer to that struct. If that seems confusing, see my answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10325505/objective-c-union-vs/10325743#10325743).

Personally, I don't like typedefs that hide pointers like this one, because it's hard to tell by looking at the code whether you need to use `a.b` or `a->b`.

Comment: Thanks, Tim. It compiles and executes. Now I'm trying to figure out how to look at what `v_cont` contains (I removed the `1`) to see if I can get to what I want. Good tips in this post (`-E`), too.

Comment: FWIW: I may have found the source for `N_VectorContent_Parallel`. Here: https://simtk.org/api_docs/simtkcore/api_docs20/nvector__parallel_8h_source.html

Comment: Jeff: I've added a little bit at the end about how to access members of the struct. Not sure if you needed it or not, but it might help :)

Comment: Thanks, @Timothy. That's useful, because I am often confused by C's pointer syntax. But right now I was just looking at the data in `gdb` to find out if it's returning the global or local vector. Unfortunately, all that work you did posting and it looks like `NV_CONTENT_P` is still only returning the local vector. :( There doesn't seem to be a method which returns the global vector, so that's what I'm still seeking (but at least I learned something along the way).